# Counting number of swaps in Bubble Up?

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I'm pretty new to Python and the assignment given was to use two functions bubble_up and bubble_sort to count the number of total swaps and total sorts executed in the program. I know that there is an issue with the total swaps looping, what in my code do I need to change to have it output a single line of total swaps instead of it showing me the number of swaps every iteration of bubble sort.

code:

```
def bubble_up(my_list):
    swap = 0
    total_swaps = 0
    for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
        if (my_list[i] > my_list[i+1]):
            temp = my_list[i]
            my_list[i] = my_list[i+1]
            my_list[i+1] = temp
            swap += 1
            
    total_swaps += swap
    print('Total swaps: ', total_swaps)        
    return my_list

def bubble_sort(my_list):
    count = 0
    has_swapped = True

    while(has_swapped):
        has_swapped = False
        for j in range(len(my_list)):
            bubble_up(my_list)       
            count += 1  
    
    print('Total bubble ups: ', count)
    return my_list

my_list1 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

print(bubble_sort(my_list1))
print()
```

and this is my output:

```
Total swaps:  5
Total swaps:  4
Total swaps:  3
Total swaps:  2
Total swaps:  1
Total swaps:  0
Total bubble ups:  6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And this is what I WANT the output to look like:

```
Total swaps:  15
Total bubble ups:  6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: the reason why output looks like that is because You call the function in a loop

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are counting `total_swaps` inside of `bubble_up`, broadly speaking, the internal variables of a function are erased the moment the function returns, unless you use a static variable (you can read more about them [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-declare-a-static-variable-in-a-function-in-python)).

So `bubble_up` is adding `swaps` to `total_swaps` (which is 0), printing `total_swaps` and then returns `my_list` and forgets about `swaps` and `total_swaps`, since the print is inside of `bubble_up`, every time that you call the function it will print a line.

There are several avenues to fix that:

- Return `swaps` in `bubble_up` and carry the total count in `bubble_sort`.
- Use a global variable to carry the sum so that the `bubble_sort` function can also be cognizant of it.
- Use a static variable so that the total sum doesn't reset to 0 every time you call the function `bubble_up`, and print only when the time is right to avoid multiple prints.

Also note that `bubble_up` returns `my_list`, but in `bubble_sort` there is nothing receiving the return.

Since you said this is an assignment I won't share code, if you want you can implement all the fixes, that way you will add more tool to your code arsenal.